# C++ subclassing in template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have a given C++ code using templates and declaring a class `C<T1, B1<T2> >` with a class `B1` as template argument. I now want `C<T1, B2<T2> >` to do exactly the same as for `B1` except some functions that I redeclare explicitly for `B2`. Below is a small example by inheriting `B2` from `B1`.

```
template <typename T1>
class B1 {};

template <typename T1>
class B2: public B1<T1> {};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class C;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class C<T1, B1<T2> >
{
public:
    C(int i) {
        // do sth.
    }
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
int getVal(C<T1, B2<T2> >& b2) {
    return 2;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
int getVal(C<T1, B1<T2> >& b1) {
    return 1;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
int doSomething(C<T1, B1<T2> >& c) {
    return getVal(c);
}

int main()
{
    C<int, B1<int> > c1(1);
    C<int, B2<int> > c2(1);
    cout << doSomething(c1); // output 1
    cout << doSomething(c2); // output 2
    return 0;
}
```

I want to change the implementation of `getVal()` without having to redeclare `doSomething()` and `C<T1, B2<T2> >`. Unfortunately this does not work (error: variable `C<int, B2<int> > c2` has initializer but incomplete type).

Is there any elegant way without having to redeclare `C` and all of its functions?

P.S.: fixed declared functions in main() according to comment.

Comment: I'd fix the two *functions* `c1` and `c2` you're declaring in `main()` first.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem, but maybe you might want to use template template parameter http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters .  Like this: `template <template <class> class B, class T1, class T2> int doSomething(C<T1, B<T2>>& v) {... }`

Comment: @u2348349: like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e193cd6d84ec398e) ?

Comment: The problem is not in templates. `doSomething` has **only** base reference and it can't call first `getVal`. Here - http://ideone.com/Hcwt1J - is a more simplified example of a problem

Comment: not sure I follow all the monikers, but is [**that**](http://ideone.com/m0iJL0) what you're trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ template specialization is based off pattern matching.  It does not use inheritance.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> class C<T1, B1<T2> >
```

only matches `B1`,  As far as the above is concerned, `B2` is an unrelated type.  Your error happened long before the `doSomething` code, it is a red herring for now.

The first thing to do is fix the above snippet:

```
template <class T1, template<class>class B, class T2>
class C<T1, B<T2> >
```

now it pattern matches both `B1` and `B2`.  Next do the same to `doSomething`:

```
template <class T1, template<class>class B, class T2>
int doSomething(C<T1, B<T2> >& c)
```

and the code should work.

Further restriction can be done via SFINAE if needed.